# WordPress atom plugin create post based group chat with API

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, plugins

There is issue to create group while publish the post so I want to create post based group. Is there any example / sample of API calling?

I have added the plugin of atom WordPress chatting on my site and expecting to enable the post base group chat from backend but its not available there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have just saw there is api and fixed it just want to share my api code with my software developers here it is the api i have called after post is published in my site

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.cometondemand.net/api/v2/createGroup',
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            'Api-Key: your-atom-apikey'
        ],
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> "GUID=GroupId&name=Groupname"

        ]);
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        $err = curl_error($curl);
        
        curl_close($curl);
        
        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            echo $response;
        //  echo "<script>alert(".$post_id.")</script>";
        
        };
```